# Cookie will not set in woocommerce_subscription_status_pending-cancel WooCommerce hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have the following code I am trying to implement in a WooCommerce store using the `woocommerce_subscription_status_pending-cancel` hook

```php
add_action('woocommerce_subscription_status_pending-cancel', 'set_gravform_cancel_cookie');

function set_gravform_cancel_cookie($subscription_id) {
    setcookie("gravform4", "hello", time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
}
```

I am trying to set a cookie that after a customer cancels a subscription.

But for whatever reason the cookie will not set in this wc hook.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should only use `$subscription` as a parameter, and not `$subscription_id`.

That seems to be a mandatory parameter for this dynamic change action. Take a look here: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/action-reference/#section-2